# Insert an arbitrary timestamp

Tags: org-mode, time-date

`C-c .` could insert the timestamp of the current date and `C-u C-c .` insert the current datetime.

I find it very difficult to insert an arbitrary datetime.

[image]

Operations over Calendar are invalid since the focus stay on the mini-buffer.

A work-around solution to insert  <2019-08-09 Fri>

1. M-x calendar to select year 2019, month of August, Day of 09
2. C-x o switch to other buffer from the calendar
3. C-c < (org-date-from-calendar)

Is there a handy way to insert a specified timestamp? or how could scroll the Calendar after strike `C-u C-c .`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To insert a timestamp four months from today, press: `C-c . +4m RET` and the +4m cookie shifts the date for you. Likewise, use -4m to insert four months *before* today (y, m, w, and d letters are all valid).

Use `S-arrows`, `<`, and `>` for navigation. See the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-date_002ftime-prompt.html#The-date_002ftime-prompt) for more information.

Comment: add the reference [8.2.1 The date/time prompt](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-date_002ftime-prompt.html#The-date_002ftime-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this for one of my libraries. It returns a string formatted as an Org time stamp.

```lisp
defun my-org-time-stamp (&optional time inactive)
  "Return an Org time stamp.

TIME is specified as (HIGH LOW USEC PSEC), as returned 
by `current-time' or `file-attributes'. The 
`org-current-time' is used unless non-nil.

INACTIVE means use square brackets instead of angular 
ones, so that the stamp will not contribute to the agenda.

Examples:
(my-org-time-stamp nil t)
\"[2020-01-27 Mon 21:37]\"
(my-org-time-stamp nil nil)
\"<2020-01-27 Mon 21:38>\""
(let ((time (or time (org-current-time))))
(if inactive
        (org-format-time-string "[%F %a %H:%M]" time)
(org-format-time-string "<%F %a %H:%M>" time))))
```

Using this, you could create a function which prompts for the time and then inserts the resulting time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

@jagrg has helpfully answered the question you probably really meant to ask, namely "how do I enter the date exactly seven months ago?" You should and did accept that answer.

For completeness, to answer the question as asked, typing the following 15 individual keystrokes in order:

```
C-c
.
1
9
-
8
-
9
SPC
1
2
:
3
4
RET
```

will insert `<2019-08-09 Fri 12:34>`.

Notes:

- In this case, the calendar's default three-month display is no help. In other cases, you should use the calendar window for reference, not input. Or simply ignore it; I rarely even glance at the calendar when entering dates and times.
- Entering a time works even without the `C-u` prefix; the only difference is that the initial suggested completion does not display a time.

Answer (score 0):

jajrg has the info you want.

but just to add a small detail:

`C-c .` prompts you to insert a active timestamp. it appears in your agenda and is surrounded by `<` `>`.

`C-c !` prompts you to insert an inactive timestamp. it doesn't appear in your agenda and is surrounded by `[` `]`.

once created, you can also change the date by ensuring point is on the timestamp and using `S-<right>` and `S-<left>` to shift back/forward by one day, and `S-<up>` `S-<down>` do move by one unit of whatever point is currently over (year, month, or day, also hour and minute if you have them).

(full info: https://orgmode.org/manual/Creating-Timestamps.html#Creating-Timestamps.)